# How to disable dragging with mouse click any images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have an image `<img src="fullscreen.jpg" />` for online driving exams, where the questions are asked using image text and with image embedded. When anyone click the image and drag the mouse it moves the image.

But how can i stop this dragging? So that nobody is allowed to do so.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$('#id-of-your-image').mousedown(function(){return false});
```

Of course you may have to use other selector as in your example image has no id attribute.

Comment: You could use $('img') to target all images on your site, but as DzikiMarian said, its only a matter of changing the selector to your needs.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using jQuery, you're looking for the `dragstart` event.

```
$("img").bind('dragstart', function(){
    return false; 
});
```

Comment: +1 I tried yours. But i have some flying texts using position:absolute; In that case it selects all image and texts. But the .mousedown works very nicely. Exactly how i needed.

Comment: you can change the selector from "img" to "#your-unique-image-id"

Answer (score 1):

Try any of these 3 if you can't or don't want to use an `id` or `jQuery` (cross-browser performance has not been tested):

```
<img src="http://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo3w.png" ondragstart='return false;'/>
<img src="http://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo3w.png" onmousedown='return false;'/>
<img src="http://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo3w.png" onmousedown='return false;' ondragstart='return false;'/>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9eCgh/)